# A problem of methods

Tags: probability, algorithms, linear-programming

I am very confused with this problem of methods that have left me, besides being long I do not know if I really accept accept the offer of the courts, I leave the problem:

"Technically Techno has several patents for different storage devices that are used in computers, cell phones and a range of products. A competitor recently introduced a product based on a technology similar to something patented by Technically Techno last year. Techno sued the competitor for the violation of his rights Based on the echos of the case, just like the record of the involved lawyers Technically Techno believes that he has a $40\%$ probability of that price $\$ 300,000$ if the petition arrives To the courts Has A $30\%$ probability of granting only $50,000$ if a trial and win and a $30\%$ chance of losing the case and no money is obtained. The estimated legal cost of a court is $\$ 50,000$. However, the other Company has offered to pay technically $\$ 75,000$ to settle the dispute in a lawsuit The estimated cost of $\$ 10,000$ if Technically Techno maximi The expected gain. Should I accept the settlement offer out of court? "

Should I accept the offer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This site works better if you show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Sounds a home work to me...